# Angular JS: how to stop two way binding from happening

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple script that contains angular js

```
 <script>
        var delightApp = angular.module('delightmeter', []);
        delightApp.controller('delightController', function ($scope) {

            $scope.delightScore = 0;
            $scope.test = function () {
                if (isNaN($scope.delightScore)) {

                    // do not bind if this happens
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
```

The html of the above script is

```
<div id="angularapp" data-ng-app="delightmeter" data-ng-controller="delightController">
    <input id="Text1" type="text" data-ng-model="delightScore" />
        {{delightScore}}

        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" data-ng-click="test()"/>
    </div>
```

As we know in angular two way binding happens whatever may be the value in `$scope.delightScore` it gets bound to the html page.
Is there any way to stop this binding from happening ?

Comment: You can create a secondary variable, bind to that, and reassign it only when the test passes.

Comment: If it must be a number, then why do you use `type="text"` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than binding to the variable directly, Bind to a function that does your check

```
<div id="angularapp" data-ng-app="delightmeter" data-ng-controller="delightController">
<input id="Text1" type="text" data-ng-model="delightScore" />
    {{ValideDelightScore()}}

    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" data-ng-click="test()"/>
</div>
```

And in your controller define:

```
    $scope.ValideDelightScore = function () {
            if (isNaN($scope.delightScore)) {
                return "";
            }else{
               return $scope.delightScore
            }
        }
```

Comment: doesn't prevent the model from changing, only the display. Now suppose that `delightScore` gets sent to server you have a disconnect between display and actual if value doesn't pass the condition. Far simpler to use another variable and assign new value to original if it passes

Comment: @charlietfl totally agree, the above approach if you want the display the model when a particular condition is met

Comment: so it is just a bad practice that could end up with unexpected (and difficult to test) results in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that because you are explicity binding the `model` in both scopes. And even if you could you should'n mess with the Angular life-cycle, or you are going to have a bad time.

The right way to achieve what you need is, or using solution purposed by @Shivas Jayaram, or use a filter in where you don't want to display the `model` if `isNaN`.

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
.filter('NaNFilter', function($moment, $translate) {
  return function(value) {
    if(isNaN(val)) {
      return '';
    }
    return value;
  };
});
```

And in your template:

```
<div id="angularapp" data-ng-app="delightmeter" data-ng-controller="delightController">
    <div>Show delightScore if !NaN: {{delightScore | NaNFilter}}</div>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" data-ng-model="delightScore" />
        {{delightScore}}

        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" data-ng-click="test()"/>
    </div>
```